# Validity of android licence?

Tags: android, android-lvl

If i implement the android LVL for licensing my android application , i still have a few unanswered questions on my mind

1. If user buy's the license , what will be the validity of user to use my application ? can i set the validity e.g (Allow paid user to use all features of my application for LIMITED 1 Year. after that again ask the user to buy/renew the  license)
2. Can i provide a free trial for 15 days of my application , then block a few features of  the application asking user to buy the premium version using the in app billing ?
3. Idea for implementing the in app billing
4. Is only GOOGLE CHECK OUT a legal / possible way , pay pal implementation is safe/correct  ?

Any information for the above will be extremely helpful :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 and 2 -- no, trials are not currently supported. If they buy your app, they can use it forever (well at least until it is available in the store), and on multiple devices. Not sure what you mean with 3. For 4, you need to consult a lawyer to be sure, but generally you can't use third party payment providers (e.g., PayPal).

Comment: Thanks for the support 

Still have a few things on mind ...

1. Then how is application like kaspersky or other antivirus softwares able to provide their licensed services only for 1 year , and then they ask to renew or re-buy the license ? 
Any clue or idea for such a implementation

2. I meant by point no.3 in the question was the best way or how to go about for the in-app billing implementation